# Android Call Recording not getting stopped when the call hangs up

Tags: android, audio-recording, telephony, android-mediarecorder

```
    public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        MediaRecorder callrecorder;
        Boolean recording = false;
        private static boolean ring = false;
        private static boolean out = false;
        private static boolean callReceived = false;
        String outNumber;
        Location location;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
                outNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                Log.d("outNumber", outNumber);
            }

            //Check if Checked In
            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String check = prefs.getString("isCheckedIn", null);
            if (check.equals("Yes")) {

                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                try {
                    Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
                    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    //Get incoming number and phone state
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                    String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
``                    Log.d("State", state);
                    // Get location
                    try {
                        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //Start switch case to switch between Phone States
                    switch (state) {
                        //If Phone is idle
                        case "IDLE":
                            Toast.makeText(context, state + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //Stop recording
                            if (recording) {
                                stopRecording();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            break;
                        //If Phone is Answered
                        case "OFFHOOK":
                            out = true;
                            callReceived = true;
                            PreferencesHelper Prefs = new PreferencesHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
                            String checked = Prefs.GetPreferences("isCheckedIn");
                            if (checked.equals("Yes")) {
                                //Start Recording
                                if (!recording) {
                                    startRecording();
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                         ring = false;
                            }
                            break;
                        //If Phone is Ringing
                        case "RINGING":
                            Toast.makeText(context, state + "" + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            ring = true;
                            callReceived = false;
                            break;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }//End onReceive

        void startRecording() {

            String fname = "/sales/rec" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + ".amr";
            callrecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            callrecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
            callrecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
            callrecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            callrecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + fname);

            try {
                callrecorder.prepare();
                callrecorder.start();
                recording = true;
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        void stopRecording() {

            callrecorder.stop();
            callrecorder.reset();
            callrecorder.release();
            recording = false;
        }
    }
```

This is my code and call recording is fine but the problem is the recording does not stop at the time of disconnection and also is this is the best practice to record a call or is there any other stable/safe way to do the same?